Bounding the sum $f(x)=-\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{p\le x}\log(p)-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{p\le x}p\cdot \log(p)$
Consider the function $$f(x)=-\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{p\le x}\log(p)-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{p\le x}p\cdot \log(p).$$
In my recent work, I need to get an explicit [rather than asymptotic] upper bound of this function.
It is easy to see that $\sum_{p\le x}\log(p) = x + O(x/\log(x))$, and $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{p\le x}p\cdot \log(p) = \frac{1}{2}x+ O(x/\log(x))$, hence $f(x)\le A \cdot x/\log(x)$ for some $A>0$.
I am wondering how to bound $f(x)$ with an explicit (or even better) upper bound?
Thank you for reading this post.

It seems like partial summation (see, for example, Appendix A in Montgomery--Vaughan) together with explicit bounds for the error term in the prime number theorem (such from this preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03134 ) should suffice to give bounds of the type you desire. Have you tried that?

There's a large body of literature on bounding sums of this sort. If for example, you use the Rosser-Schoenfeld bounds, you should be able to get an explicit bound through a laborious but straightforward process.  See also later papers by Dusart bounding the $n$th prime number which will likely give tighter bounds at the cost of them having a larger C where the bound becomes valid for all $x> C$.

Just an $\epsilon$-expansion of my comment on the question. Recall the usual notation for the Chebyshev $\vartheta$-function:
$$\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p\leqslant x} \log p. $$
Then, using the notation of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals (e.g., see pp. 486-488 of Montgomery--Vaughan), one can write
$$f(x) = -\frac{x}{2} + \vartheta(x) - \frac{1}{x} \int_{2^-}^x t d[\vartheta(t)].$$
Integrating by parts in the integral,
$$f(x) = -\frac{x}{2} + \vartheta(x) - \frac{1}{x}\Big(x\vartheta(x)\Big) + \frac{1}{x}\int_{2^{-}}^x \vartheta(t) dt.$$
Writing $\vartheta(x) = x + E(x)$ and simplifying the resulting expression, we see that
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\bigg(\int_{2^{-}}^x E(t) dt -2\bigg).$$
Now, if you plug in an explicit upper bound for the error term in the prime number theorem, you get an explicit upper bound for $f(x)$.
